# jQuery: Floating info pop-up in the most elegant and efficient way

Tags: jquery, html

I want to implement a floating information pop-up (or how to call it), that appears when the cursor is over an element and stays within a fixed distance to the cursor. For instance something more less like here:

http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2008/09/15/business/20080916-treemap-graphic.html

Say, I have 100 divs for which I want the pop-up to appear. I thought about doing it in two ways:

1. For each div, in HTML code I have a hidden pop-up div, on `mousemove` I show it, move to the cursor's position and on `mouseleave` I hide it. Each div has its `mousemove` (x100) and `mouseenter` event bound (x100).
2. I have a single `mousemove` for the main area of the page,for each div on `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` I show / hide a pop-up. There is a single `mousemove` (x1) and `mouseenter` + `mouseleave` for each div (x100).

My questions are:

1. Is This The Way? Or there is some better jQuery mechanism to use?
2. Is there any difference in performance when I have a single `mousemove` and 100 `mousemove` callbacks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> floating information pop-up (or how to call it)

these are called tooltips (there are [many](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/stylish-jquery-tooltip-plugins-webdesign/) javascript/jQuery plugins for these)

in regards to rolling your own, you seem to have it figured out, you'll need to create `mouseover`/`mousemove`/`mouseout`  events for the divs.  With jQuery this would look something like:

```
var $tooltip = $('#tooltip'), // reusable jQuery obj
    offset = {x: 20, y: 20}; // tooltip offset from the cursor

$('#container div').mouseover(function() { // over
    $tooltip.show()
}).mousemove(function(e) { // move
    // set the positioning with offset
    $tooltip.css({left: e.pageX + offset.x, top: e.pageY + offset.y}) 
    // set the tooltip HTML contents
    $tooltip.html('[your content]');
}).mouseout(function() { // out
    $tooltip.hide();
});
```

[example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/uJmQE/)

As for performance: [jsperf - mousemove parent vs children](http://jsperf.com/mousemove-parent-vs-each-child)

setting the `mousemove` event on the container does indicate a faster operations/sec in the above test case but in real world use it's unlikely you'd notice a difference.

here's an example where only the container's `mousemove` event is set

[example jsfiddle #2](http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/uJmQE/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Have you just considered using premaid plugin for jquery like qTip ? http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/download